# CasperJSでブラウザの動作状況をGUIで確認する方法

Tags: casperjs

CasperJSを初めて触っています。

`Seleinum-WebDriver`を使って作業するときはまずChromeかFirefoxのブラウザの動作状況がわかる形で動作確認を行い、全部の処理が正常に終了出来てることを確認できたらPhantomjsに切り替えるという方法を使っていたのですが、

CasperJSですとHeadlessのブラウザしか使えないようでどうやって動作確認をすればよいかわからず困っています。

CasperJSではどのように動作を確認するのが定番の手順になるんでしょうか？

#### 追記

環境はOSXになります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS 1.1 から、 Gecko ベースの [SlimerJS](https://slimerjs.org/) がサポートされています。レンダリングエンジンが変わってしまいますが、この方法はいかがでしょうか？

インストールしてパスを通し、 `casperjs --engine=slimerjs hoge.js` とするだけで使えます。

※Windowsだと `mktemp` を入れる必要があったり、「無効なスイッチ」と表示されたりしましたが、動いてはいるようです

[CasperJSがGecko(SlimerJS)にも対応していたので試してみたメモ - ハードコイルド・ワンダーランド](http://weathercook.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2013/07/20/181631)

Comment: slimerjsはHeadlessですよね？ Headlessしか使えないCasperJSでどうやってGUIでの確認をするかという事を聞きたかったのですが…。何か私が勘違いしているのでしょうか？

Comment: と私も思ったのですが、[CasperJSでブラウザを表示する方法としてそれが挙げられていた](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22841354/2818869)ので試してみたところ、ウィンドウが表示されたので、こういうことなのかなと（完全なブラウザではなかったのですがxulrunnerだからのような気がします）。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたのですがウィンドウが立ち上がりませんでした。環境は Casperjs1.1.0-beta3、Slimerjs 0.9.5でOSX上で行いました。もしかしてLinux環境で動かせばウィンドウが表示されるのでしょうか？

Comment: 念のため、ウィンドウが小さくて気づかなかった、なんてことはないですよね・・・？ http://stackoverflow.com/a/22858886/2818869

Comment: …すいません、もう一度確認したらターミナルの背後で実行されているのを見つけました。